# How to append a string in front of all elements in any List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is there any way I can insert a prefix string `"/directory/"` in front of all elements in the list `["file1.json", "file2.json"]`?

Result I'm looking for would be `["/directory/file1.json", "/directory/file2.json"]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the linq extension method: `Select()`

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "file1.JSON", "file2.JSON" };

var directory = "/directory";

myList = myList.Select(filename => Path.Combine(directory, filename)).ToList();
```

This will execute the `Path.Combine(directory, filename)` foreach item in the list. I'm using the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) method, because thats the best way to concat directories/filenames, because it should be platform independend.

Comment: Actually your code snippet is not  platform independent. On Windows it produces something that is neither path nor url.

Comment: It's an example for the `Select()` method.

Comment: Then use simple string concatenation instead of `Path.Combine`. Examples that produce meaningless results are not so useful IMO :)

Comment: Feel free to improve answers, so we all can learn it the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
List<string> yourlist = new List<string> { "file1.JSON", "file2.JSON" };
var directory = "/directory/";
yourlist = yourlist.Select(f => string.Concat(directory,f)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers using `Select` are actually creating a new list if you really want to change the values in the existing list then just use a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
    fileList[i] = @"/directory/" + fileList[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension method [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx). There are two ways of calling `Select`:

1. Method syntax

   ```
   var originalList = new List<string> { "file1.json", "file2.json" };
   var list = originalList.Select(e => "/directory/" + e);
   ```
2. Query syntax

   ```
   var originalList = new List<string> { "file1.json", "file2.json" };
   var list = from e in originalList select "/directory/" + e;
   ```

Both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the following, Which will give you a List as per your requirement:

```
string stringToappend=@"/Directory/";
List<string> JsonList= new List<string> (){"file1.JSON","file2.JSON"};
var AppendedLis=JsonList.Select(x=> Path.Combine(stringToappend, x)).ToList();
```

**Note :-** The LINQ Extension method `.Select` help you to do this operation, Which will internally iterate through each element in the collection and append the required string with each item and Gives you the List as per your requirements